# How do I load custom scripts and styles for a page?

Tags: pages, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, scripts, css

Different pages often need different set of scripts and styles for them.

I use functions.php and construction like this to load scripts and styles:

```
function load_assets() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css');
   wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_assets' );
```

I know I can put some condition here like this:

```
is_page()
```

but is there a better way?

Suggestion:

Can wp_register_script() be used to target specific pages?

Comment: I don't know any better way. Why does the is_page() bothers you ?

Comment: It doesn't really bother me, but I don't like that if you need to enqueue custom scripts for 'about' page you need to go to dashboard, look this page id and yeah...

Comment: `is_page` also accepts a title or slug. there's also `is_page_template` that lets you target php template files.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may add [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.  See the examples below:

```
function load_assets() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css');

   // loads on any 'page' post type
   if( is_page() ){
       wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
   }

   // only loads on the page with a slug of 'home'
   if( is_page('home') ){
       wp_enqueue_script('home-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js');
   }


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_assets' );
```

For other examples of `is_page()` usage, see the codex page: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was told in comments above. Thanks for detailed example.

Comment: No problem ! Would you mind accepting the answer if it is solves your question?

Answer (score 1):

For admin you can do in this way.

```
function load_assets( $hook ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        // enqueue here
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_assets', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: You mean it will work only for admin? It's something, but I need all users solution.